# probability question involving numbers 100 to 999 inclusive

Tags: probability

A whole number between 100 and 999 inclusive is chosen at random. Find the probability that it is exactly divisible by 3. If it is exactly divisible by 3, what is the probability that it is exactly divisible by 9?

Comment: How many of these numbers are exactly divisible by $3$. Just count. And how many of these are exactly divisible by $9$? Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Answer (score 1):

Please do not count...

For each $ab$ in $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}\times\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ there are $9$ numbers in the set which end by $ab$. Among them, exactly $3$ are multiples of $3$ and exactly $1$ is a multiple of $9$. Thus the probability that a number chosen unformly at random in the set $\{100,101,\ldots,999\}$ is some multiple of $3$ is **exactly** $\frac13$ and the probability that it is some multiple of $9$ is **exactly** $\frac19$.

This applies to every set $\{9k+i+1,9k+i+2,\ldots,9\ell+i\}$ with $0\leqslant k\lt\ell$ and $i\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can count total no of numbers divisible by 3 in given range and then divide it with the range, fraction is the answer. 
For conditional probability count no of numbers divisible by 9 in given range and then divide it with no of numbers divisble by 3.
Use 3*3=9 expression while calculating conditional probability. It will simplify calculation. 
If the total no of numbers divisible by 3 is even then conditional probability will be 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

For a $3$-digit number $abc$ (with $a\not=0$) to be divisible by $3$, the sum of the digits, $a+b+c$, must be divisible by $3$.  No matter what $b+c$ is, there will be $3$ choices of $a$ that make $a+b+c$ divisible by $3$, out of $9$ choices altogether.  So the probability is $3/9=1/3$.

For divisibility by $9$, the same trick works, except now there is only *one* choice of $a$, so the probability is $1/9$.  (And this make the conditional probability, which is what the OP asked about, equal to $(1/9)/(1/3)=1/3$.)

Note, this works for $n$-digit numbers in general, not just $3$-digit numbers.